# Json data parsing error for flot graph

Tags: json, ajax, parsing, external, flot

```
datapie = [
{"label": "Running",  "data": [19.5], "color":"#e1ab0b"},
{"label": "Stopped",  "data": [4.5], "color":"#fe0000"},
{"label": "Terminated",  "data": [36.6], "color":'#93b40f"}
];
```

Getting an error
    TypeError: d is undefined

Please help!!

data is called using ajax

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed how you're calling flot (i.e. what options, and the actual `$.plot` bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data doesn't look to be in the correct format. It should look like this:

```
datapie = [
{label: "Running",  data: 19.5, color: '#e1ab0b'},
{label: "Stopped",  data: 4.5, color: '#fe0000'},
{label: "Terminated",  data: 36.6, color: '#93b40f'}
];
```

Tutorial - http://digitalunion.osu.edu/2011/12/21/make-graphs-and-charts-with-jquery-using-flot-js-%E2%80%94-a-brief-tutorial/

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Rnusy/5/